# ABPersonViewController does not dismiss the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpersonviewcontroller

I have a strange thing happening in one of my applications.

I am presenting an `ABPersonViewController` within an `UINavigationController`.
The code is pretty straight forward:

```
ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (book, recordID);

ABPersonViewController *view = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
view.addressBook = book;
view.displayedPerson = person;
view.allowsActions = NO;                
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

If the user taps on Notes field - the keyboard will show.

Now if "Back" button is pressed, the view is dismissed, but the keyboard is still being displayed. It's like no responder was called to dismiss it (although I don't think this is the case).

I have checked in phone Contacts app - but this is not happening.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have an app with the same issue on iOS 9. My iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8.4.1 doesn't run into this.

Comment: Note that ABPersonViewController is deprecated in iOS 9. If you're only supporting iOS 9 and newer, you should be using the new Contacts framework.

Comment: @bneely - please add this as an answer to accept it. This was the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABPersonViewController is deprecated in iOS 9, replaced by the ContactsUI framework. This is what you should use if your minimum iOS version is iOS 9.